# Determine which table was updated in database level trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am creating a database level trigger which should only perform a certain action based on which tables were updated.

With a regular trigger I would just use `IF UPDATED(column)`.

Is there some way to determine not just the column that was updated but also the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create DDL TRIGGER ON UPDATE

[CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

> DDL triggers, like standard triggers, execute stored procedures in
>   response to an event. But unlike standard triggers, they do not
>   execute in response to UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements on a table
>   or view. Instead, they primarily execute in response to data
>   definition language (DDL) statements. These include CREATE, ALTER,
>   DROP, GRANT, DENY, REVOKE, and UPDATE STATISTICS statements. Certain
>   system stored procedures that perform DDL-like operations can also
>   fire DDL triggers.

Comment: Thanks, how then would be the best practice to catch all updates to any table in the database? Is this at all possible without putting a trigger on each table?

Comment: @ose - it's exactly as you suppose/fear - if you want to track `UPDATE`s in every table, you have to apply triggers/CDC/change tracking to each table.

Comment: I enjoy writing triggers.. hope I still feel that way after I write about 350 to all do the same thing... :(

Comment: @ose: time to write a stored proc that iterates through the Information_schema.tables view and auto-generates the appropriate triggers. I've done it, and I am horrible, so you can too.